# How to start building Augmented Reality applications for android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am new to Android. I need to make an app which is related to Augmented Reality but I am not at all familiar with this concept. Can anyone provide a good link to get started?

Comment: unfortunatly people with low information are in this site,voting down any question they dont know!!!

Comment: Search on google lot of material available there.

Answer (score 2):

greate question.augmented reality means to show user additional information about where he is or what to do.for example imagine you are driving a car,then you see the name of streets on car front glass,you see traffic info , gps info and lots of thing.or you see an arrow on street showing you the way home!!!
this is called augment reality.look at this [pic](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.autoblog.com/media/2010/08/01-augmented-630.jpg) or [this](http://telematicsnews.info/wp-content/uploads/general/bmw%20aug%20real1.jpg) one
Now first find out what additional info you can deliver to your user depending on your app.and then begin the work